# Linked List Sorting with Strings In C

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I have a struct, with a Name and a single Node called nextName

It's a Singly Linked list, and my task is to create the list, based on alphabetical order of the strings.

So iff i enter  Joe  Zolt and Arthur i should get my list structured as

Joe

Than

Joe Zolt

Than

Arthur Joe Zolt

I'm having trouble implementing the correct Algorithm, which would put the pointers in the right order.

This is What I have as of Now.
Temp would be the name the user just entered and is trying to put into the list,
namebox is just a copy of my root, being the whole list

```
 if(temp != NULL)
      {
              struct node* namebox = root;
              while (namebox!=NULL && (strcmp((namebox)->name,temp->name) <= 0))
              {
                      namebox = namebox->nextName;
                      printf("here");
                 }
                temp->nextName = namebox;
    namebox = temp;
    root = namebox;
```

This Works right now, if i enter names like CCC BBB than AAA

I Get Back AAA BBB CCC when i print

But if i put AAA BBB CCC , When i print i only get CCC, it cuts the previous off.

Edit:

Can someone show me what the code would look like, i cant get it down.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter AAA, BBB and then CCC `namebox` is always `NULL` when while loop finishes.

And then you are doing:

```
// namebox is null
temp->nextName = namebox;
// namebox = CCC
namebox = temp;
// root = CCC
root = namebox;
```

So that's why you are getting only `CCC`.

Now, what you need to do in those cases is make sure `CCC` is added at the end of the list and do not change root.

Comment: Ah ok i understand, now its just implementing it.

So would that mean i should create a scenario for when strcmp((namebox)->name,temp->name) >= 0 (key here being >= )?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is [Insertion Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

When you enter AAA, BBB, and finally CCC, `namebox` is `NULL` when the while loop is done.

Then when you do `temp->nextName = namebox`, `namebox` is `NULL`. After that you set `namebox` to `temp` (which holds `CCC`). Finally you set `root` to `namebox` which sets it to `CCC` also. This is why you get `CCC`.

In your algorithm you need to handle the case where you're adding something at the end or the middle of the list and not change root in those cases. In fact, this should be the general case. Adding things at the front and end should be your special cases.

Comment: so i need 1 case for strcmp((namebox)->name,temp->name) = 0

One for strcmp((namebox)->name,temp->name) <= 0

and one for strcmp((namebox)->name,temp->name) >= 0   ??

Comment: more or less. There should be a way to structure your algorithm so that you can handle this elegantly. Insertion sort isn't any more different than inserting into a linked node, and is actually one of the simpler insertion-sort algorithms.

Comment: Err... I meant "linked list" not "linked node".

Answer (score 0):

```
if(temp != NULL)
{
    struct node* namebox = root;
    while (namebox!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(namebox->Name,temp->Name) > 0) // if temp comes before this
        {
            temp->nextName = namebox->nextName;
            namebox->nextName = temp;
            //printf("here"); I'm guessing this is debugging stuff?
        }
        namebox = namebox->nextName;
    }
}
```

this is for general insertion but you have to do special cases when you add the first name and add to the beginning of the list

Answer (score 0):

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    struct node
    {
        char data[100];
        struct node* next;
    };
    
    struct node* head = NULL;
    
    struct node* getnode(char *v)
    {
        struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        strcpy(newnode->data,v);
        newnode->next = NULL;
        return newnode;
    };
    
    void insert(char *v)
    {
        struct node* newnode = getnode(v);
        newnode->next = head;
        head = newnode;
    }
    
    void print()
    {
        struct node* temp = head;
        //struct node* end = NULL;
        int c = 1;
        while(temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            c++;
        }
        temp = head;
        char x[100];
        for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
        {
            temp = head;
            while(temp->next != NULL)
            {
                if(strcmp(temp->data,temp->next->data) > 0)
                {
                    strcpy(x,temp->data);
                    strcpy(temp->data,temp->next->data);
                    strcpy(temp->next->data,x);
                }
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            //end = temp;
        }
        temp = head;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\t",temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("\n\n The Length of the list : %d",c);
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        printf("Hello world!\n");
        char v[100];
        while(1)
        {
            printf("enter a string : ");scanf("%s",v);
            if(v[0] == 'Q' || v[0] == 'q')
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                insert(v);
            }
        }
        print();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain how your code answers the question.